# Finding largest from each subarray of length k

Tags: algorithm

Interview Question :- Given an array and an integer k , find the maximum for each and every contiguous sub array of size k.

```
Sample Input :

1 2 3 1 4 5 2 3 6 

3 [ value of k ]


Sample Output :
3
3
4
5
5
5
6
```

I cant think of anything better than brute force. Worst case is O(nk) when array is sorted in decreasing order.

Answer (score 2):

Just iterate over the array and keep `k` last elements in a [self-balancing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree) [binary tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree).
Adding element to such tree, removing element and finding current maximum costs `O(logk)`.

Most languages provide standard implementations for such trees. In STL, IIRC, it's `MultiSet`. In Java you'd use `TreeMap` (map, because you need to keep count, how many times each element occurs, and Java doesn't provide Multi- collections).

Pseudocode

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    tree.add(a[i]);

    if (tree.size() > k) {
        tree.remove(a[i - k]);
    }

    if (tree.size() == k) {
        print(tree.max());
    }
}
```

Comment: @Moron Standard heaps in most languages don't support removal (or even locating) of arbitrary element. You can definitely build such uber-heap by adding a hastable, but you will have to write it yourself.

Comment: Gah! You are right! For some weird reason, I was trying to remove the max! I was going to +1 this anyway, but I am out of votes... You are right one could use a hashtable though, but then it is pointless. A tree would be better. The only reason to suggest the heap was to make O(1) one of the operations :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can actually do this in O(n) time with O(n) space.

Split the array into blocks of each.

`[a1 a2 ... ak] [a(k+1) ... a2k] ...`

For each block, maintain two more blocks, the left block and the right block.

The ith element of the left block will be the max of the i elements from the left.
The ith element of the right block will be the max of the i elements from the right.

You will have two such blocks for each block of k.

Now if you want to find the max in range `a[i... i+k]`, say the elements span two of the above blocks of k.

`[j-k+1 ... i i+1 ... j] [j+1 ... i+k ... j+k]`

All you need to do is find the max of RightMax of `i to j` of the first block and the left max of `j+1 to i+k` of the second block.

Comment: Nice idea. It's worth noting, that 'blocks' don't have to be physically separate, it can be just 2 arrays of length n. As for applicability of the heap, I've commented on my answer about it.

Comment: @Nikita: If you liked this problem, I suggest you look at the Range Minimum Query problem. In O(n) time you can do a pre-processing step so that _any_ query of the form Min (a[i], ..., a[j]) (and not just j-i = k) can be answered in O(1) time. I agree with your heap assessment.

Comment: I think this solution is no better than the 1st answer,since you need to sort each blocks to keep its property. So the total time complexity will be O(n/k * k * logk) = O(nlogk), which is the same as the first answer, am I right?...

Comment: @superb: No, as you walk the array, you can create one of the two blocks. You don't need to sort. To create the other block you walk in reverse.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is the solution which you are looking for:

```
def MaxContigousSum(lst, n):
m = [0]
if lst[0] > 0:
    m[0] = lst[0]
maxsum = m[0]
for i in range(1, n):
    if m[i - 1] + lst[i] > 0:
        m.append(m[i - 1] + lst[i])
    else:
        m.append(0)
    if m[i] > maxsum:
        maxsum = m[i]
return maxsum

lst = [-2, 11, -4, 13, -5, 2, 1, -3, 4, -2, -1, -6, -9]
print MaxContigousSum(lst, len(lst))
**Output**
20 for [11, -4, 13]
```

Comment: I recommend you to read to the OP's question again, and carefully. The question doesn't ask for "Max Contiguous Sum", but rather it looks for "the max element" in each of these sub arrays.